# AES/ECB/NoPadding Unsafe Encryption Mode error

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-security

I have an error in Google play, AES/ECB/NoPadding Unsafe Encryption Mode Usage, I rely on it to communicate with beacons in the field, and for my API (which also uses this encryption).  It contains no user data, just internal protocol data to communicate with Beacons in the field (I encrypt this internal data with AES/ECB/NoPadding). I need a solution to be able to update the app, since the latest one has been rejected on Google Play, and I also need to be able to maintain compatibility with devices in the field, since these devices have to decrypt the received data, and their Firmware only supports AES/ECB/NoPadding.

I have also tried AES/GCM/NoPadding, but i don't see how to implement it and  maintain compatibility, without completely changing the current communication flow with devices in the field, which would break the compatibility.

So i need this encryption to dinamically share internal data with beacons in the field, it is not used to save any user data.

Comment: I am also struggling with this, using a third-party library that uses AES/ECB/NoPadding. It's very strange that Google have only just blocked this without any deprecation warnings - it's a total pain for us right now as we have to change a go-live date for one of our apps until we can figure out how to move forwards. 

Strange I can't see any formal communications about this issue or when Google blocked it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the mode of your encryption.
Right now you are using "AES/ECB/NoPadding", replace it with "AES/GCM/NoPadding".
REF: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10046138